Cannot find an embed for this URL
I'm working on a Wagtail project and trying to add embedded videos (from Vimeo) to my homepage using EmbedBlock. However, I'm unable to embed any video links through the Wagtail admin. I’ve tried embedding videos in EmbedBlock, RichTextField, and URLField, but none of them work.
I don’t get any specific error messages—just:

"Cannot find embed for this URL"
"The page could not be saved due to validation errors"

Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it?
Any help would be appreciated!
Here is my models.py:
from wagtail import blocks
from wagtail.models import Page
from wagtail.fields import RichTextField, StreamField
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock
from wagtail.embeds.blocks import EmbedBlock

class ImageAndEmbedBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    image = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
    video = EmbedBlock(required=False)

    class Meta:  # noqa
        label = "Media"


class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    carousel = StreamField(ImageAndEmbedBlock(), null=True, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("body"), FieldPanel("carousel")]

I tried adding this to the settings but it made no difference:
# commented out the import because it did not work neither
# from wagtail.embeds.oembed_providers import vimeo

vimeo = {
    "endpoint": "https://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.{format}",
    "urls": [
        r"^https?://(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com/.+$",
        r"^https?://player\.vimeo\.com/.+$",
    ],
}

WAGTAILEMBEDS_FINDERS = [
    {
        "class": "wagtail.embeds.finders.oembed",
        "providers": [vimeo],
    }
]


What version of Wagtail are you using? Have you tried various vimeo url's?
I've tested this with 6.2,using https://vimeo.com/channels/bestofstaffpicks/991662980?autoplay=1
The embed is found and rendered correctly. I haven't customised the finders at all.
Have you tried various Vimeo url's? I don't know about Vimeo, but on YouTube, uploaders can select to not allow their videos to be shared via embeds. If you hit one of these then the error is the same as you saw.

I'm using 6.2.2 it wasn't working with 6.2.1. Yes I tried different links from vimeo none of them work. could you try with this link? "https://vimeo.com/936416569"

Yep, works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/6lGfqnr
